# Connecting Two Nouns 雀跃?

Tags: sentence-structure

他心里一段说不出来的雀跃
I know what it means, but how come I can just connect two nouns? 雀跃has to be nominalised since it has 一段 and 的. Or if 雀跃 is a verb how come it can the 的 and measure word.
The only other explanation I have is 雀 means sparrow while 跃 is a verb so it is the first characterbeing modified.

Comment: 雀跃(excitement)is a single noun here

Answer (score 1):

他心里一段说不出来的**雀跃** = 他心里一段说不出来的**雀跃般的欢喜**。

In 说不出来的雀跃, 说不出来的 is an adjective, and 雀跃 is a noun.

雀跃 is simplified from 雀跃般的欢喜, which still means happiness but more artistic and literary. For example,

她心里的雀跃全都写在她的脸上。= She could not conceal her happiness.

雀跃 is a noun that is constructed in the **subject + verb** form. This formation is not very popular in Chinese nouns, but there is another example.

地震 = Earthquake

Comment: So the entire sentence is one modified noun?

Comment: 他心里一段说不出来的雀跃 is a noun phrase. You can modify it to make it a complete sentence as 他心里**有**一段说不出来的雀跃， or 我知道他心里一段说不出来的雀跃。

Answer (score 0):

> 雀跃 has to be nominalised ....

No, 雀跃 is a compound word that consists of two roots/words,

- 雀跃 = sparrow/bird (n) + jump/frolic (v), and the result is a noun that means "played boisterously/happily".

Other words with the same root/word "跃" include "活跃", "跳跃", and "跃进".

Note: Examples of English compound words with more than one root - "[type][writ]er", "[cow][boy]s", "[tele][graph]ically", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a typo with 段？Could try 种 or 股。 Without 有 the sentence is still acceptable to people I asked.

他心里（有）一股说不出来的雀跃。
He felt an indescribable joy.

雀跃：如雀跳跃。比喻欣喜兴奋到极点

雀跃, officially *jump for joy* often just gets translated as *joy*.

It is very inconsiderate of the Chinese not to use suffixes to clearly identify the word class of a word.

刺激：excite, excitement

她总渴望刺激。
She always craved excitement.

享受：enjoy, enjoyment, pleasure
扩展：extend, extension

Oh really? English doesn't clearly separate words classes either? But surely, we should write *talkment* as the noun of talk???

开始: start, a start
这将是个令人雀跃和成功的开始！

There is no clear distinction between word classes in Chinese. This points to an error in the Western system of word classes, not an error in the Chinese language.

Don't be at all surprised if you think a Chinese word is a verb or an adjective or whatever, but you find that word being used, unchanged, as a member of a different word class!

(PS sparrows are so happy because they are incredibly promiscuous birds. One-track little fliers!)